# Whats the maximum number of points inside a rectangle such that no two points have a distance less than one

Tags: optimization, packing-problem

Find the maximum number of points inside a 3 by 4 rectangle (the points CAN also lie on the perimeter) with the constraint that no two points have a distance less than one.

someone suggested the following solution:
we consider the side of length 3 and we pick 4 points evenly distributed (including the endpoints) and we can do the same for the other side but with 5 points , and partition the rectangle into 12 unit squares to finally get that the maximum number of points is 20
[image: illustration]

- How can we prove that this arrangement guarantees the maximum number of points?
- Is there a way to generalize and solve this problem for any m by n rectangle, or to use other shapes (like rectangles , trapazoids etc..)?

please put more Tags for this problem as you see fits.

Answer (score 3):

If we place a disk with radius $\frac 12$ on each point, the constraint is now that that no two disks can intersect (and their centers must lie inside the rectangle). This is now a [circle packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing) problem. It's well-known that the optimal circle packing is hexagonal, so I would suppose that the answer to the question is along those lines.

I think that in the particular case of the 3 by 4 rectangle, there is no better packing. However, for larger shapes, the optimal packing will approximate a hexagonal one.

Comment: Basically now the problem is to find the best way to pack circles in a 4 by 5 rectangle. But as you said, Probably the above packing is the optimal packing for this case.